# Weblogic Server failed to start -NullPointerException

Tags: java-7, weblogic11g

I was unable to start the server , its getting stopped with below error. Can any one please suggest solutions?

```
<AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.DeploymentManager.getPendingDeploymentsForEditLockOwner(DeploymentManager.java:360)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.removePendingUpdateTasks(EditAccessImpl.java:560)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.undoUnsavedChanges(EditAccessImpl.java:555)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.acquireLock(EditAccessImpl.java:264)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.startEdit(EditAccessImpl.java:289)
at weblogic.management.deploy.ApplicationsDirPoller.removeStagedFilesForAppsRemovedSinceLastShutdown(ApplicationsDirPoller.java:426)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.initializeApplicationPoller(DeploymentServerService.java:274)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.startAdminServerDeploymentService(DeploymentServerService.java:233)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.init(DeploymentServerService.java:154)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentPreStandbyServerService.start(DeploymentPreStandbyServerService.java:26)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after adding container-descriptor in weblogic.xml as below.

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
 <wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:timeout-secs>900</wls:timeout-secs>
    <wls:persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</wls:persistent-store-type>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```